# Can not workout the new html Classes for elements

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I  have been using the following code to extract data from FB and it has been working fine. Recently FB changed their class for elements and I am having problems working out what the NEW class are. I have been stuck on this for a few weeks now and can not seem to work them out. I am aware that IE no longer works with FB so with my limited knowledge ON VBA I put this together to use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP. As I said it worked fine, but now it does not extract the data as the CLASS have changed and I can not work them out

I have reduced the size of the code for this post, the original code pulled off all the date from the page, I was able to navigate to the child elements as well. I have tried several things like search via "Span" & "ID", but I can not work out the class or the child node.

**Questions**

1. What are the classes for the elements?
2. Will **MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP** still WORK or is it not able to extract from FB ANYMORE?

**Background** -
In column 1 Sheet "Facebook" I have a list of url, the code would run through each url and get the data, it no longer gets the data, see image below.

[image: FB Image]

This is a normal link [FB Link](https://www.facebook.com/Prime-Motors-of-London-158009737576021/about)

They all land on the "About" page, In the past I was able to pull off all the data, now nothing. *If someone could please show me what the class are for 2 items **(Address and email)** I am sure I could work out the rest for myself*. I have not added any FB HTML in this post as I am not sure what to post for the class that I am after, therefore I have included an image.

[image: FB HTML]

**Idealy I would like to stick with my code as I am very limited in VBA and I do understand my code.**
I have left 2 of the old classes in the code, see below

```
Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet, link As Variant
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim EndRow As Long
    Dim doc As htmlDocument
    Dim varLinks As Variant
    Dim myCounter As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSheet = wb.Sheets("Facebook")
     
    StartRow = wsSheet.Cells(wsSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    EndRow = wsSheet.Cells(wsSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    varLinks = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(wsSheet.Range("A" & StartRow & ":A" & EndRow))
    
    With Sheet9
        lastrows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    counter = 0
    For Each link In varLinks
       
        Set doc = NewHTMLDocument(CStr(link))
'''''Element 1 Column B '
       If doc.getElementsByClassName("'_2yau")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 2).Value = "-"
        Else
            wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 2).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("'_2yau")(0).innerText
        End If
'wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 2).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("'_2yau")(0).innerText.getElementsByTagName("Span")(1).innerText

''''Element 2 Column C
     On Error Resume Next
        If doc.getElementsByClassName("'_50f4")(1) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 3).Value = "-"
        Else
        On Error Resume Next
            wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 3).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("'_50f4")(1).innerText
        End If
        
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the site in a browser, use an extension that blocks javascript. As you can see the site is completely generated by javascript. So a simple http request won't help you. There's an ajax call somewhere that generates the html. Might be possible to find it if you search long enough.

Comment: Thanks Charles, but what you are talking about is way out of my depth.  "There's an ajax call somewhere that generates the html. Might be possible to find it if you search long enough".  As I mentioned FB does not work with IE and I am using VBA with MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP. If MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP can no longer take off the data then I will have to give this a miss. As anything beyond this will be out of my depth. I don’t fancy using selenium as it’s an extra add-on.

If I am reading your reply correct then this is not possible with MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP, is that correct?

Comment: getElementsByClassName is not approprate because they seem to be using hashed class names, which could change anytime. So, you can either chain getElementsByTagName or you can copy the full xpath, and use that with selenium or you can create custom function to select element from the full xpath.

Comment: check out for custom function idea: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/127407-vba-xpath-with-id-something/

Comment: If you search for "Springbank" then you can still find it in the response body. So you might be able to parse it out there.

Comment: earthguestg - could you please change a bit of my code to include "getElementsByTagName" so i can see what to do and i will due the rest, I am limited in vba

Comment: Its in json, not a html element